# error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments - something about threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, client-server

I got this error:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

I don't know why but i found that its something about the threads (if I comment out the lines about the threads it compiles).
the problem is in the lines:

```
thread t(&TriviaServer::clientHandler, this->_socket);
```

and:

```
thread t(&TriviaServer::clientHandler, client_socket);
```

from the functions serve() and acceptClient.

my code:

```
#include "TriviaServer.h"

#define PORT 8820
#define IFACE 0


TriviaServer::TriviaServer()
{
    this->_db = DataBase();
    this->_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (this->_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        throw exception(__FUNCTION__ " - socket");
}

TriviaServer::~TriviaServer()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->_connectedUsers.size(); i++)
        delete this->_connectedUsers[i];
    this->_connectedUsers.clear();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->_roomList.size(); i++)
        delete this->_roomList[i];
    this->_roomList.clear();
    TRACE(__FUNCTION__ " closing accepting socket");
    try
    {
        closesocket(this->_socket);
    }
    catch (exception e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    catch (...) {}
}

void TriviaServer::serve()
{
    bindAndListen();

    thread t(&TriviaServer::clientHandler, this->_socket);
    t.detach();

    while (true)
    {
        TRACE("accepting client...");
        acceptClient();
    }
}

void TriviaServer::bindAndListen()
{
    struct sockaddr_in sockAddr = { 0 };
    sockAddr.sin_port = PORT;
    sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = IFACE;

    if (::bind(this->_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        throw exception(__FUNCTION__ " - bind");
    TRACE("binded");

    if (::listen(this->_socket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        throw exception(__FUNCTION__ " - listen");
    TRACE("listening...");
}

void TriviaServer::acceptClient()
{
    SOCKET client_socket = accept(this->_socket, NULL, NULL);
    if (client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        throw exception(__FUNCTION__);

    TRACE("Client accepted !");

    thread t(&TriviaServer::clientHandler, client_socket);
    t.detach();
}

void TriviaServer::clientHandler(SOCKET)
{
    //TODO
}
```

Is someone know the reason and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
thread t(&TriviaServer::clientHandler, this->_socket);
```

Since `&TriviaServer::clientHandler` is defined as:

```
TriviaServer::clientHandler(SOCKET);
```

The first argument to be passed to a call via the *function pointer* `&TriviaServer::clientHandler` is an implicit `this` parameter of type `TriviaServer`, or a pointer to an object of `TriviaServer`. You need to pass that before any other argument the function declaration takes. So you want to do:

```
thread t(&TriviaServer::clientHandler, this, this->_socket);
```

Comment: Yes, I understood the reason and now it works. Thank you!